# odeint: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, types, differential-equations, odeint

I can't for the life of me find a solution to this. Here is my code, it is a pretty straightforward ode so I have no idea where I'm going wrong:

```html
H0 = float(3*10**(17)) # seconds 
me = 0.000511 # GeV/c^2
e0 = 55.26349406*1e+15 # e^2⋅GeV^−1⋅m^−1
a = 1/137 
nb = 0.016

def efrac(Xe, x, H0, me, e0, a, nb):
    A = (9.78*a**2)/(H0*me**2)
    dXedx = A*(np.log(x)/(x**3)) * ((1-Xe)*((me*e0)/(2*np.pi))**(3/2)*exp(-x)-(x**(3/2)*Xe**2*nb))
    return dXedx
    
x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 1000)
Xe0 = 1.0 
sol = odeint(efrac, Xe0, x, args=(H0, me, e0, a, nb))
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not start with a clean work space, the function `exp` was probably imported from `sympy`.

After correcting that to `np.exp`, I get the obvious division-by-zero error of the first evaluation at `x=0` from `np.log(x)/x**3`.